# HttpWebRequest Failing, Can't Figure out Why

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, compact-framework

I have a WP7 app where I'm trying to reconstruct an HTTPWebRequest that I have successfully written elsewhere using the synchronous methods (pasted at end) but which doesn't work in WP7, I assume because I'm doing something wrong with the Asynchronous versions of these methods.

I believe the issue stems from the fact that the non-working code on the Compact Framework can only send a bytearray[] - I don't have the option of sending the json string. If I send a bytearray in the code that works, I get an error there too. Is there a different option?

Here is my code - this does not work. The exception is thrown on the 2nd line of the last method - "Using(var respons ...)":

```
public void CreateUser()
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://staging.cloudapp.net:8080/api/users/");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(RequestCallback), request);
    }

    private static void RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;

        using (Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
        {
            User user = new User("Windows", "Phone", "USCA");

            Formatting formatting = new Formatting();
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, formatting, settings);

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, json.Length);
        }

        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ResponseCallback), request);
    }

    private static void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result))
        {

            using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
                string responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

This code works (non-compact framework version of the same request):

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://staging.cloudapp.net/api/users/") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "text/json";
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            User user = new user("Other", "Guy", "USWC");
            Formatting formatting = new Formatting();
            JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user, formatting, settings);

            writer.Write(json);
        }

        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return responseText;
        }
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the type of exception you're seeing?

Comment: It's a System.Net.WebException - "The Remote server returned an error: Not Found." Not very helpful. But the fact that I can take this code and run it elsewhere against the same API, and have it work if I don't do the ByteArray encoding, and have it fail when I do encode to ByteArray, makes me believe that that is the problem. I just don't know how to get around it ...

Comment: Hmm ... never solved this, and then I cam back to it 2 weeks later and it was working all of a sudden. I'll try to figure out what changed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - I'm not sure why this problem went away. I liked @RowlandShaw's suggestion, but I didn't actually change anything in the json. Wish I could give a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

looks like the server is responding with a "404 not found". Does the resource you are requesting exist at the server?

Comment: Hi Feroze, I can confirm that it does exist - if I copy the json variable into Fiddler, I get a 201 created response - so it would seem that something is simply wrong with my HttpWebRequest and my use of its asynchronous methods ... I meant to include that info in my original post. I'll update it.

Comment: And - that URL isn't the full URL for the endpoint I'm calling - I can't put the actual URL up here in the forum, if that's where you got the 404 :).

Answer (score 1):

Does your JSON contain any non 7-bit ASCII characters, as you are currently doing:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, json.Length);
```

The number of bytes might not be identical to the number of characters in your string, which could lead to a malformed request.

It would be worthwhile using something like Fiddler to verify what is actually going over the wire from the emulator or phone (there are [instructions on the Fiddler website](http://www.fiddler2.com/phone/) for how to do this)

Comment: Thanks Rowland, I'll check it out!